# I am trying to make a slider for svg slides with jquery only without using any plugins

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

here I am trying to make a svg slider without any plugins
I have some complicated html/css which I can not implement into the code I am trying to use

here's the code in code pen

https://codepen.io/j-tap/pen/EeyRrV

whenever I try to put an svg slide inside an 'li' I end up with a very big photo that doesn't relate to the original slide

[link to screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iKyN.jpg)

that's the complicated html/css I am trying to implement in the slider:

```
    <!--

    Task 1 
    
    Final output should be a simple slider like the one in the image here
     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PEK5pR9kdN8rHQto2xm-vVZQ9qjPdAIA/view?usp=sharing
    - slider is triggered by the dots at the bottom
    - slider is switching between different Quotes evey 3s
    - don't use any ready slider plugin or script.
    - you can use JS and jQuery only
    - you can preview the changes by openning Preview link top right menu, in a new tap.
    - you all customization code should be here, <style> ur css </style> and <script>  your magic scripts </script>

--->









<style type="text/css">
    

/* Styles for testemolials section */
.testemolials-sec {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.item-wrap {
  /*max-width: 270px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  padding: 0px 24px;
}
.testi-item-paragraph {
  font-family: 'Myanmar MN';
  color: #6c7b93;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 132px;
}
.testemolials-sec h4 + hr {
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.testemolials-sec .testi-item-paragraph + span + hr {
  width: 75%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 22px
}
.testemolials-sec svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
.testemolials-sec .dquate-before svg {
transform: rotate(-180deg);

}
.dquate-before {
  color: #0074b6;
  display: block;
/*  transform: rotate(-45deg);*/
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  right: 38px;
}
.dquate-after {
  color: #0074b6;
  display: block;
/*  transform: rotate(-45deg);*/
  text-align: right;
}
.cus-title {
  color: #0074b6;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}


</style>






<div class="testemolials-sec text-center page-width">
    <div class="page-width">
     
    <div class="section-header text-center">
      <h2> (Task 1 ) WAS TEILNEHMER ÜBER UNSERE KURSE SAGEN</h2>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="grid page-width">
    <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half text-center testi-item">
      <div class="item-wrap">
        <span class="dquate-before">
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px"><g><g id="right_x5F_quote"><g><path d="M0,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H0z" fill="#0074b6"/><path d="M20,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H20z" fill="#0074b6"/></g></g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg>
        </span>
        <p class="testi-item-paragraph text-left">{{section.settings.testi1_content}}</p>
        <span class="dquate-after">
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px"><g><g id="right_x5F_quote"><g><path d="M0,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H0z" fill="#0074b6"/><path d="M20,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H20z" fill="#0074b6"/></g></g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg>
        </span>
        <hr>
        <strong class="cus-title text-left">{{section.settings.testi1_title}}</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half text-center testi-item">
      <div class="item-wrap">
        <span class="dquate-before">
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px"><g><g id="right_x5F_quote"><g><path d="M0,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H0z" fill="#0074b6"/><path d="M20,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H20z" fill="#0074b6"/></g></g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg>
        </span>
        <p class="testi-item-paragraph text-left">{{section.settings.testi2_content}}</p>
        <span class="dquate-after">
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px"><g><g id="right_x5F_quote"><g><path d="M0,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H0z" fill="#0074b6"/><path d="M20,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H20z" fill="#0074b6"/></g></g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg>
        </span>
        <hr>
        <strong class="cus-title text-left">{{section.settings.testi2_title}}</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item text-center testi-item">
      <div class="item-wrap centered-testi">
        <span class="dquate-before">
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px"><g><g id="right_x5F_quote"><g><path d="M0,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H0z" fill="#0074b6"/><path d="M20,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H20z" fill="#0074b6"/></g></g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg>
        </span>
        <p class="testi-item-paragraph text-left">{{section.settings.testi3_content}}</p>
        <span class="dquate-after">
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px"><g><g id="right_x5F_quote"><g><path d="M0,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H0z" fill="#0074b6"/><path d="M20,4v12h8c0,4.41-3.586,8-8,8v4c6.617,0,12-5.383,12-12V4H20z" fill="#0074b6"/></g></g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg>
        </span>
        <hr>
        <strong class="cus-title text-left">{{section.settings.testi3_title}}</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Task 1",
    "class": "index-section",
    "settings": [
 {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "testimonials section"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "testi1_content",
      "label": "testimonial1 text"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "testi1_title",
      "label": "testimonial1 teller"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "testi2_content",
      "label": "testimonial2 text"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "testi2_title",
      "label": "testimonial2 teller"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "testi3_content",
      "label": "testimonial3 text"
    },

    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "testi3_title",
      "label": "testimonial3 teller"
    }
    ],
    "presets": [
      {
        "name": "TAsk 1",
        "category": "Tasks"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

any idea how to make it into a slider?

Comment: Why is there XML in your html? SVG elements have been part of HTLM5 since it replaced HTML4.01-transitional, so just use the SVG element tag. Don't embed full SVG documents in your HTML (`<?xml...`), you just start with `<svg width="..." height=".." viewBox="...">` no namespaces etc, just normal HTML syntax. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction to learn more about this works in modern HTML.

Comment: I am not the one who wrote the html/Css, it's a task assigned like that

Comment: And I already embedded it without the XML and it resulted to the photo in the screenshot

Comment: If that code is in the task, talk to whoever wrote the task: that is 100% invalid HTML and will cause all kinds of weird broken behaviour.